# Initializing parameters in a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am getting an exception when executing a stored procedure:

> Procedure or function 'spAddItemByUrl' expects parameter '@userId', which was not supplied.

But I have initialized it, so what I'm dong wrong?

Here is the stored procedure:

```
create proc spAddItemByUrl
    @title nvarchar(50),
    @body nvarchar(50),
    @link nvarchar(50),
    @userName nvarchar(50),
    @url nvarchar(50),
    @userId int,
    @feedId int
as
begin
    insert into feed(title, body, link) values(@title, @body, @link)
    select @userId = id from users where name = @userName
    select @feedId = id from feed where title = @title
    insert into userstofeed(userid, feedid) values(@userId, @feedId) 
    insert into feedurl(url, feedid, userid) values(@url, @feedId, @userId)
end
```

And here's the C# code.
The exception is thrown when I call `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
connection.SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", urlFeed.Url);
connection.SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", item.Title.Text);
connection.SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", item.Summary.Text);
connection.SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link", item.Id);
connection.SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", user);
connection.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.SqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: `Procedure or function 'spAddItemByUrl' expects parameter '@userId', which was not supplied.` should be enough to understand where is the error

Comment: Your stored procedure expects 7 parameters but you supply only 5. Guess UserId and FeedId should also get a value.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That code is far from ANSI SQL...)

Comment: @Valentini i knew there is the problem., i don't know hot to initialize local variable not a parameter, that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added `@userId int, @feedId int` to the list of parameters for your SProc, but from the query it looks like you don't want them to be provided by the user. You can declare them inside the SProc to make them "local".

i.e.

```
create proc spAddItemByUrl
    @title nvarchar(50),
    @body nvarchar(50),
    @link nvarchar(50),
    @userName nvarchar(50),
    @url nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    DECLARE @userId int, @feedId int;

    insert into feed(title, body, link) values(@title, @body, @link)
    select @userId = id from users where name = @userName
    select @feedId = id from feed where title = @title
    insert into userstofeed(userid, feedid) values(@userId, @feedId) 
    insert into feedurl(url, feedid, userid) values(@url, @feedId, @userId)
end
```

Comment: This approach has the potential to fail if there are multiple records for the username or title.

Comment: @DanBracuk I agree, but no more so than the original. It's a good idea to also put suggested improvements on the original post so the OP will get notified and benefit from the wisdom.

Comment: Thanks, i was needed to declare local variables and don't know how to do that, because i'm new in t-sql.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified

```
connection.SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", user);
```

but not @userid

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add default values to your stored procedure arguments you can do the following:

```
create proc spAddItemByUrl
...
@userId int = 0, /* or whatever you want the default value to be */
@feedId int = 0
```

If you decide to call your stored procedure, you then only have to pass the five arguments provided in your code, and the values `@userId` and `@feedId` will be 0. If you decide to specify values for those two parameters in your calling function, then the values you pass will be used.

Since your stored procedure doesn't use those parameters though, you should remove them from the section they are in.

Instead just do

```
declare @userId int = select id from users where name = @userName
declare @feedId int = select id from feed where title = @title
```